# Databinding datagrid through a dataset datasource: Image column not showing image but system.byte[]

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, gridview

I have dragged and dropped a gridview into designer and configured the datasource to new SQLDataSource where I chose a Image table. In that, there are 3 columns (Id, Name, Image as image datatype). However once I configured and run the app, it doesn't show me the image column. Please help me, I want to display the image from the SQL DB to the datagrid 3rd column
...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

@Divine: If you post code it will be more helpful.

Few suggestions.

1. Do not use auto-generated columns of datagrid, as datagrid doesn't support image template column by default.
2. You should search to create a DataGrid Template columns. That will help you to display image or help you to customize your data and present in certain format.

This article might help you. : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479316.aspx

Comment: take a look at this link too. http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t71090-image-in-template-column-in-datagrid.html

Comment: Hi Priyank, thank you, surely will go through these links now. But I want a simple way of displaying 3 columns in gridview from sql database. The columns are 1. int column ID, 2. varchar column Name, 3. image column Actual Picture.

Comment: @Divine: I think if your images are stored directly in a database, they must be stored in some binary format. You should first figure out how to retrieve them from DB. And with datagrid, I am sure you must have to go with template columns.

Comment: @Divine: look at this forum: http://forums.asp.net/t/1202090.aspx/1?Retrive+Images+from+SqlServer+in+ASP+NET+